# Does every closed, densely defined operator in a Banach space have a closed, densely defined extension on a Hilbert space?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, unbounded-operators

Assume that $H_1,H_2$ are [separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space) [Hilbert spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), $B$ is a separable [Banach space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) and $H_1\subset B\subset H_2$. Assume further that the [inclusion mappings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map) are continuous and have dense images.

Given any [closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators), [densely defined operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_defined_operator) $T$ in $B$, is it then true that there exists a closed, densely defined operator $\tilde T$ in $H_2$ which extends $T$ (viewed as an operator in $H_2$)? In other words, is $T$ closable as an operator in $H_2$?

In a [paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/47524041_Adjoint_Operators_on_Banach_Spaces) by Gill, Basu, Zachary and Steadman, it is pointed out that it is well known that the answer to my question is 'yes' (See Theorem 4). They argue that the adjoint of $T$, say $T':B'\rightarrow B'$, is a closed operator, which is densely defined if we restrict it to $H_2'\subset B'$. However, it is not explained why the restriction of $T'$ is densely defined, and it does not seem obvious to me that it is.

This question is related to another question of mine, [Pointwise approximation of a closed operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099109/pointwise-approximation-of-a-closed-operator).

*Gill, Tepper L.; Basu, Sudeshna; Zachary, Woodford W.; Steadman, V.*, [**Adjoint for operators in Banach spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-03-07204-6), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 132, No. 5, 1429-1434 (2004). [ZBL1048.46014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1048.46014).

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to be no. A counter example follows.

Let $H_1$ be a separable Hilbert space with norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ and let $U$ be a bounded, injective, self-adjoint operator on $H_1$ with $0\in\sigma(U)$. Then we may consider the completion $H_2$ of $H_1$ with respect to the norm $\lVert \psi\rVert_2 := \lVert U \psi \rVert_1$. Since $U$ is not boundedly invertible, we have $H_2\supsetneq H_1$. On the other hand, $H_1$ is clearly dense in $H_2$. Furthermore, the extension $\bar{U}:H_2\rightarrow H_1$ of $U$ to $H_2$ is a unitary transformation.

For definiteness, let $H_1=\ell^2$, and let
\begin{align}
U e_n &= n^{-4}e_n + n^{-3}e_1, \mbox{ if }n\geqslant 2,\\
U e_1 &= a_1 e_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-3}e_n,
\end{align}
with $a_1=2\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^{-2}$. Furthermore, consider the closed, densely defined operator $T$ defined by $Te_n=n^4e_n$. Then [$U$ is bounded and positive definite with $0\in\sigma(U)$, and $UT$ is not closable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2340504/161825). Since $H_1\subseteq H_2$, we may consider $T$ as a densely defined operator in $H_2$, and we denote this operator by $T_2$.

Suppose now that $T_2$ is closable, with closure $\bar{T}_2$. Then $UT\subseteq \bar{U}\bar{T}_2\!\!\upharpoonright_{H_{1}\cap\mathrm{dom}(\bar{T}_2)}$. Since $\bar{U}$ is boundedly invertible, $\bar{U}\bar{T}_2$ is closed, which ensures that $\bar{U}\bar{T}_2\!\!\upharpoonright_{H_{1}\cap\mathrm{dom}(\bar{T}_2)}$ is closed. But then $UT$ is closable, and this is a contradiction.